# Save user inputs from web-form to a text file (on cloud : URL) and read the same

Tags: javascript, html

I want to save user inputs from web-form to a text file (on cloud :URL) and want to display the same data (user inputs) on another page. Not sure how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something server-side to handle saving the data.  This will depend on either the cloud service you elect to use (i.e. storing on Amazon's S3) or which language you intend to write your own server-side code in.

JavaScript executes on the client and can send/receive information from the server/host, but it cannot modify files on a server/host.  If you intend to write your own and host it yourself, you could use Node.js, PHP, ASP.Net, etc. on the server.